# $var == false not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an expression like this in which value of $var is false:

```
    if (! isset($var) || (isset($var) && $var == false)) {
           // This should be executed
    }
    else if (isset($var) && $var == true) {
           // This is executed
    }
```

I want the first expression to be executed. What is wrong in above code?
Please help me out

Output of var_dump($dump):

```
    string 'false' (length=5)
```

Comment: What has been assigned to $var ?

Comment: Why your boolean `false` is a string `'false'`?

Comment: what about this http://kunststube.net/isset/

Comment: @Bondye the $var is a GET variable [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17268813/1057527](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17268813/1057527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of false is coming from a get request and i should have done like this:

```
    if (! isset($var) || ( isset($var) && $var == 'false' ))
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write the logic as below:

```
if (isset($var) && $var) {
   // Do other thing
} else {
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: I tried but if $var is false then it is entering the if block.

Comment: @khushalbokadey Sorry, but code never lie, show the result of `var_dump($var)`

Comment: @xdazz: Edited the o/p in the question

Answer (score 2):

Your have answered your own problem with var_dump()

```
string 'false' (length=5)
```

You are trying to compare a string to a boolean. Try:

```
$var === 'false'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are trying to do with this

```
if (! isset($var) || (isset($var) && $var == false))
```

is exactly the definition of the empty function (or it's negation in fact). See the man page here http://php.net/empty

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
if ( !isset($var) || ( isset($var) && !$var )) {
       // Do something
}
else if ( isset($var) && $var ) {
       // Do other thing
}
```

Or simply try like

```
if ( !isset($var) || ( !$var )) {
```

Comment: I think isset will return false for the $var = false

Answer (score 0):

```
if (! isset($var) || (isset($var) && $var == 'false')) {
           echo 'false';
    }
    else if ((isset($var)) && ($var == 'true')) {
           echo 'true';
    }
```

use this code. if any value is assigned to a variable it will be considered true in a Boolean expressions.That is why the second condition is executed.

Comment: Read this [http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: @machineaddict I have corrected my answer. ($var==false) will evaluate true Only when $var is empty string or not set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter and the value of `$var` is coming from a get request then you dont need to type such a long expression. This will also work.

```
if( !$this->input->get('get_variable_name') ) {
 // Do something
} else {
 // Do other thing
}
```

The isset thing is done by codeigniter itself. For more information visit the link below.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 0):

Note the answer of @Nathan Bishop.

```
if( empty($var) ) {
    //$var is false
} else {
   //$var exists and is true
}
```

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.
>   [Source PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

if you want play with true of false value in your url queries do it with "1" for true and "0" for false

The following values are considered FALSE:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)